# found input text inside inner div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want focus on a text input inside some div, i have this html code:

```
<div class="place">
<div class="flip">
<div class="front"><img src="myAvatar.png"></div>
<div class="back">
<div class="name">MyName</div>
<input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
<div class="button">Sign in</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

in javascript i can detect when i touch the flip div in this way:

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
            $('.flip').removeClass('initiate');
            $(this).addClass('initiate');
            //$(this).children('back').children('.password').focus();
        });
```

but i want focus on the text input, how i can find it? i have tried in this way:

```
$(this).children('back').children('.password').focus();
```

but don't work...any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the `.` from your class-selector:

```
$(this).children('.back').children('.password').focus();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UhHs8/).

But I'd suggest shortening that, for brevity, to:

```
$(this).find('.password').focus();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UhHs8/1/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).